# Beaglebone black is not detected in the PC

Tags: macos, beagleboneblack

I tried to flash my beagle bone black , and followed this link:
http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Flashing_eMMC
I changed the line 
**#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh** to **cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh** and rebooted from the terminal, after a while I observe the beagle bone is itself not detected in the PC.
I plugged and unplugged it several times but no sign of its detection. 
Although the LEDs are working fine when power on , but after some time the USER leds doesn't glow.

Comment: You can't damage the board by flashing. Do you really mean UART LEDs? Do you have a UART adapter attached? Why are you not looking at the output of it? Or did you mean the 4 User LEDs?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your concerns, I have just started with BBB so was facing some trivial problems, anyways I corrected my question , please check . Thanks .